# Button working on PC browser but not on Mobile

Tags: javascript, html

I'm designing a Captive Portal, which is just a Redirect from our firewall to the page where the user needs to fill out information, press submit and be redirected again after authenticating. everything works on my computer, but when I try and connect on my phone the button will highlight but nothing will happen.

I was reading a lot online nothing helped, I tried setting the `.click` to touchstart and touch end and none of them worked, maybe I'm putting it in the wrong spot? I'm not sure.

```
$("#login_btn").click(function (e) {
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
        var edata = $("#loginform").serialize();

        if ($("#name").val() == "" || $("#email").val() == "" || $("#contact").val() == "") {
            $("#fillall").show();
            $("#fillall").text("Please Fill All Fields");
        } else if (!regex.test($("#email").val())) {
            $("#fillall").show();
            $("#fillall").text("Enter Valid Email Address!");
        } else if ($("#name").val() != "" && $("#email").val() != "" && $("#contact").val() != "") {
            $("#fillall").hide();
            $.ajax({
                url: "add_api.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: edata,
                success: function (res) {
                    console.log('AJAX Success:', res);
      if(res == "success"){  
        $('#message').html('<label class="label label-success center-block" style="width:250px;height:auto;line-height:15px;font-size:13px;">Thanks For Submitting Details.<br>You will be redirected to url<br>in few seconds.</label>');
        
          
    
        setTimeout(() => {
            
            $('#login_btn').hide();

                // Show the OK button
                $('#ok_btn').show();
            
        
      
    }, 3000);
    }
    else{
      $('#message').html(res);
    }
        }
        });
        }
});

});
```

and my button code is :

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div style="color: white;
padding: 15px 50px 5px 50px;
float: right;
font-size: 16px;"></div>

  </nav>
  <div id="page-wrapper" style="margin:0 auto;">
    <div id="page-inner">
      <div id="confirmmessage"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
          <img src="assets/img/BettaLogoTrans.png" alt="Your Logo" class="logo-image">
          <h5></h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /. ROW  -->
      <hr />
      <div style="width:100%;"> 
</div>

        <!-- Form Elements -->
        
        <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin:auto !important;width:320px;">
          <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#000000;border-color:#000000;text-align:center;color:white;"> DETAILS BELOW </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
              <form id="loginform" action="#" method="post">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" name="contact" id="contact" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact #" />
                </div>
                <div id="message"></div>
                <label class="label label-danger center-block" id="fillall" style="width:250px;height:20px;line-height:15px;font-size:13px;display:none;">Please Fill All Fields</label>
                <button type="button" id="login_btn" class="btn btn-danger center-block" >Submit</button>
              </form>
              
  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Form Elements --> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /. PAGE INNER  --> 
</div>
<!-- /. PAGE WRAPPER  -->
</div>
<!-- /. WRAPPER  --> 
<!-- SCRIPTS -AT THE BOTOM TO REDUCE THE LOAD TIME--> 
    <!-- Script for URL Params and Button Click -->
<!-- JQUERY SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
<!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS --> 
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<!-- METISMENU SCRIPTS --> 
<script src="assets/js/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script> 
<!-- CUSTOM SCRIPTS --> 
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>


</body>
```